# How to maintain Hibernate session opened per request?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jakarta-ee, servlets

As far as I know session per request means we should use only one hibernate session per servlet request, not one session per transaction.

Consider this helper class:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // this is called by the servlet context listener
    public static void buildSessionFactory() {
        // build session factory
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    // check if the entity user already exist in the database
    public static User getUser(String email) {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User user = (User)session.createQuery("from User c where c.emailAddress like :email").setParameter("email", email).uniqueResult();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return user;
    }

    // if getUser returns null, insert this user in the database
    public static void insertUser(User user) {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

Now each method has it's own session object, but when the register servlet gets called I have to do this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    User user = // initialise user
        if (getUser(request.getParameter("email")) == null) { // session
            insertUser(user); // another session
            request.setAttribute("user", user);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("homepage.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("message", "This account already exist");
        populateFields(request);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("register.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
}
```

Now, my register servlet effectively used two sessions, vilating the pattern. I've thought of possible ways to fix:

- Set a global Session object in the hibernateUtil class, then prevent getUser from committing the transaction. I think this means every method can now use this session, even in multiple request if the transaction is not committed. My problem is what is my only operation is to get a user and nothing more?
- Let getUser return the session and pass it to insertUser, I don't know, I'm not sure if it's good to pass session objects around.
- Just get rid of the helper class and write the code directly in the servlet and remove the helper class. I really think it would simplify the management of sessions, but I might not be able to reuse some transactions.

What should I do? And are there better code that does what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The best option in this case is to have a design like this:

- Have an abstract Dao that will have a `Session session` as field and will allow the injection of this via constructor or setter (up to you). All your Daos will be subclasses of this class.
- The service classes can create a `Session session` in their methods or receive it as parameter. In this way, the service may inject the `session` to the necessary daos used in its methods. This also enables the service to start and commit/rollback a transaction.
- In case you want/need that services should be unaware of opening/closing hibernate sessions, then you may create a wrapper for the interfaces that will create a session, inject it to a service, and then execute the proper methods of the service(s). After executing the method, this wrapper will commit/rollback the operations done in the session.

If you use a framework like Spring that provides integration with Hibernate, you will see that they have a similar design:

- Dao classes must allow the injection of `HibernateTemplate` via constructor parameter or setter.
- Services will use dao interfaces as needed.
- Use of `<transactional>` or `@Transactional` will create a proxy class that wraps your service to open the session, execute the proper method of the service, and commit/rollback the operations, depending on the configuration of the transaction management done there.

Comment: I'm also wondering, should I need to write a helper class just for this? Or just write the code directly in the servlet and remove the helper class. I really think it would simplify the management of sessions.

Comment: What do you mean by creating a helper class for this? I don't see how a helper class will fit in this approach, except your current utility class that creates the `SessionFactory` and allows you to create a `Session`.

Comment: currently my helper class also contains all my transaction methods. Is it better if I just remove from the helper and write them directly in the servlet?

Comment: Servlet should be unaware of session. The service/dao should be aware of session. What I'm telling you here is that you should focus the session management in a single place. IMO the utility class shoukd only provide the method for obtaining the session.

Comment: What if rather than using getCurrentSession which closes the session automatically after commit, I just call openSession instead? That way I can call session.close at the end of the request. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a [filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) that creates the session and then stores it in the request, so you can reuse it anywhere you have access to the request object:

```
public class SessionPerRequestFilter implements Filter {
    public static final String SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "myapp.hibernate.session";

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Locate the session on the request object
        Session session = (Session) request.getAttribute(SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
        if(session == null) {
            // Create a new session
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            request.setAttribute(SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, session);
        }

        try {
            // Continue the filter chain
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        finally {
            // Close the session
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

In your servlets you then get the session by

```
Session session = (Session) request.getAttribute(SessionPerRequestFilter.SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
```

Make sure you only close your transactions and not the session in your helper classes though.

Comment: I disallow this idea because some requests do not need to operate with database. Also, this breaks the MVC pattern.

Comment: How does this break MVC?

Comment: Hibernate session relates to database management, and this goes in model. Servlets and filters remain in the controller, and should send the commands to model to update the data in the narrowest possible scope available. Using the filter option works, but there are some problems: 1) The hibernate session should be stored in web request scope, not in web session scope, 2) If I need to execute two operations and commit the results of each separately, this cannot be done since the services will share the same session, and if one fails none of the operations will be commited

Comment: 3) if I only need to fire a file download, no database access required, then this approach will open/close resources that are never used

Comment: @Raniz I'm also wondering, should I need to write a helper class just for this? Or just write the code directly in the servlet and remove the helper class. I really think it would simplify the management of sessions.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Session management is definitely up to the controller layer in MVC - the model is just a data-holder and should contain as little logic as possible. You can also control which endpoints your filter is applied to to prevent it from allocating unnecessary resources.

Comment: @morbidCode: It depends on how you want to structure your code. Personally I like to keep my servlets/controllers as light as possible and do the heavy lifting in helper classes or services.

Comment: In the apps I work with, datasource usage is handled in model, including: database, file, external service, cache, etc. This way of separating call of model in two controllers is very odd. It works, indeed, but you cannot reuse your service/dao layer in a different project.

Comment: @Raniz What if rather than using getCurrentSession which closes the session automatically after commit, I just call openSession instead? That way I can call session.close at the end of the request. What do you think?